# Template does not exist. Django looking for wrong path

Tags: python, django, templates, django-models, django-templates

im following a django tutorial but have had this error coming up for a while now. i've had the course code up next to mine to comepare it to try to find the bug but i haven't had any luck with it

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /posts/new/
posts/post_form.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/new/
Django Version: 1.11
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
posts/post_form.html
Exception Location: /Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/simplesocialenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in select_template, line 53
Python Executable:  /Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/simplesocialenv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.5.0
Python Path:    
['/Users/chrismaltez/Desktop/pycharmprojects/UDEMY/simple_social_clone/simplesocial',
 '/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/simplesocialenv/lib/python35.zip',
 '/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/simplesocialenv/lib/python3.5',
 '/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/simplesocialenv/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/simplesocialenv/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/simplesocialenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages']

Here is the postmortem traceback:

Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /Users/chrismaltez/Desktop/pycharmprojects/UDEMY/simple_social_clone/simplesocial/templates/posts/post_form.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/simplesocialenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/posts/post_form.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/simplesocialenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/posts/post_form.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/simplesocialenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bootstrap3/templates/posts/post_form.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/chrismaltez/Desktop/pycharmprojects/UDEMY/simple_social_clone/simplesocial/accounts/templates/posts/post_form.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/chrismaltez/Desktop/pycharmprojects/UDEMY/simple_social_clone/simplesocial/groups/templates/posts/post_form.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/chrismaltez/Desktop/pycharmprojects/UDEMY/simple_social_clone/simplesocial/posts/templates/posts/post_form.html (Source does not exist)

This is the last line of the traceback:

raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
```

From what I can tell, it might not be looking in the right place

```
-simple_social_clone
--simplesocial
---posts
----templates
-----posts
------post_form.html

from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url(r'^test/$', views.TestPage.as_view(),name='test'),
    url(r'^thanks/$', views.ThanksPage.as_view(),name='thanks'),
    url(r'^posts/', include('posts.urls',namespace='posts')),
    url(r'^groups/', include('groups.urls',namespace='groups')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls))
    ] + urlpatterns
```

here is project level views.py

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class TestPage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'test.html'

class ThanksPage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'thanks.html'


class HomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

Here is app level views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

from django.http import Http404
from django.views import generic

from braces.views import SelectRelatedMixin
# Create your views here.

from . import models
from . import forms

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class PostList(SelectRelatedMixin,generic.ListView):
    model = models.Post
    select_related = ('user','group')

class UserPosts(generic.ListView):
    model = models.Post
    template_name = 'posts/user_post_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            self.post.user = User.objects.prefetch_related('posts').get(
                username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username')
            )
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
        else:
            return self.post_user.posts.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['post_user'] = self.post_user
        return context

class PostDetail(SelectRelatedMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Post
    select_related = ('user','group')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username'))

class CreatePost(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, generic.CreateView):

    fields = ('message','group')
    model = models.Post

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

class DeletePost(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, generic.DeleteView):
    model = models.Post
    select_related = ('user','group')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts:all')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryet()
        return queryset.filter(user_id = self.request.user.id)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        messages.success(self.request,'Post Deleted')
        return super().delete(*args,**kwargs)
```

Here is app level urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'posts'

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.PostList.as_view(), name='all'),
    # url(r'new/$', views.CreatePost.as_view(),name='create'),
    url(r"new/$", views.CreatePost.as_view(), name="create"),
    url(r'by/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$', views.UserPosts.as_view(),name='for_user'),
    url(r'by/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.PostDetail.as_view(),name='single'),
    url(r'delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DeletePost.as_view(), name='delete'),
]
```

Here is the models at app level:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.conf import settings

import misaka
# Create your models here.

from groups.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

from django import template
register = template.Library()

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    #auto generates datetime stamp of post
    message = models.TextField()
    message_html = models.TextField(editable=False)
    #doesnt allow others to edit post
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='posts', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.message_html = misaka.html(self.message)
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            'posts:single',
            kwargs={
                'username':self.user.username,
                'pk':self.pk
            }
        )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        unique_together = ['user','message']
```

here is post_form.html

```
{% extends 'posts/post_base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block post_content %}
<h4>Create a new Post</h4>
<form id="postForm" action="{% url 'posts:create' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    <input type="submit" value="Post" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">


    </form>


{% endblock %}
```

finally here is the project templates level:

```
enter code here     </div>

    </nav>
    <div class="container mycontent">

        {% block content %}

        {% endblock %}


        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[[image]][2]

Comment: What is the root of your project `simplesocial` or `simple_social_clone`?

Comment: @guillermochamorro The  root is simple_social_clone i believe. i'll post an image of the way i have it set up. I have multiple apps within the project.

Comment: the root is where your manage.py is.

Comment: ah. in that case, the root is simplesocial.

Comment: That moment when you realize that you had your template files one level up and not actually in your template folders :(

Thanks for the help anyways man.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you have all the templates under one folder, whilst Jose (the instructor for the tutorial you're following) had them arranged per app. Make sure you have set everything right in the settings. I'm doing the same course (ps, changed groups to communities in mine):[image]